# Is my variable guaranteed to be unchanged if I interrupt my Python kernel?

Tags: python, python-2.7, interrupt

I tried finding a definite answer to this, but my Google-fu failed and I don't know enough about Python to work it out myself:

Let's say I have a simple line of code, like this:

```
nrows = df.count()  # Really large pyspark dataframe
```

I am happy that, after waiting for half an hour, my computation finally is finished. However, instead of reading the value, I accidentally trigger a recomputation. Because I do not want to wait for another half hour, I interrupt the kernel. **Is there a guarantee that nrows still contains the correct value?** Note that I assume that I interrupted long before df.count() finished.

I ran some experiments, and it *seems* to hold the correct value. However, experiments can disprove, but not prove a theory - therefore my question. Obviously, `count()` is just a simple example, I am also interested in the general case. How about lists, for example?

Comment: from my humble understanding; nrows = df.count() is broken into several lower level commands. One of which is the overwriting of nrows pointer or value. However this overwriting statement comes last and only when df.count() is finished. So it is never changed unless the function call completed / right part of the assignment is fully completed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's disassemble a similar code example:

```
import dis
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
def func():
    nrows = df.count()

dis.dis(func)
```

Output:

```
  6           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (df)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (count)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (nrows)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

In Line 6, `df.count()` is called. In Line 9, the computed value is stored in the variable `nrows`. So, if you manage to interrupt the kernel before `df.count()` returns, `nrows` will not be overwritten.